# PySpark with S3 - how to add attributes

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, emr

We are doing some EMR calculations on PySpark and outputting them to s3.
s3 invokes a lambda that adds a message to SQS which is processed by another process.
We are looking for a way to pass additional attributes to the files stored in s3, so the final process can fetch some more info about the files that are being processed.
saveAsTextFile seems to be unable to store metadata on the s3 object.
What is the best way to pass that info.

Comment: Seems like it's not possible to do so directly from Spark. Probably not going to be implemented in the near future. You can check [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17945) issue.

Comment: thanks, so do you have any alternative?